# Vtiger 6 Error on Importing CSV

Tags: php, csv, vtiger

I keep getting the same error when trying to import any sort of csv file into Vtiger 6. The export works fine but I can't get any new import to work on any module, contacts, leads, invoice.

Every time I try the import I get the following message.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach: found on modules/Import/readers/FileReader.php on line 98

modules/Import/readers/CSVReader.php on line 72

I have mapped the fields correctly and tried to find a solution to no avail.

Please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this but had this problem myself today and found the answer buried on the vtiger discussion board yet still seems to be a lot of threads asking this with no response.

The problem comes, I think, if you migrated from 5.4 to 6, fresh installs should be fine. Basically it duplicates some of the import files when it installs. Backup and then remove the resources folder from modules > import in your vtiger install and it should all be sorted!